# Linux: find first result from specified search path

Tags: linux, command-line, find, which

**If I have a colon-separated path list, much like $PATH, but not neccessarily $PATH.**

**I want to search that list for a specific file name.  However, I only want the first matching path.**

I have considered the following linux commands:

- `which`: only works for binary, and only works with $PATH variable
- `whereis`: works with particular kinds of files, and only works with $PATH variable
- `find`: does not support colon-separated path lists, and returns multiple results

**Here are some things I have tried:**

1. I have tried to use `whereis` by the following strategy

   ```
   env WHEREIS="`which whereis`" PATH="$MY_PATH_LIST" $WHEREIS "$TARGET_FILE"
   ```

   and this almost works.  However, it does not seem to return results for arbitrary file types.  It also returns multiple results, and in an awkward format.
2. I could get `which` to work by

   ```
   env WHICH="`which which`" PATH="$MY_PATH_LIST" $WHICH "$MY_TARGET_FILE"
   ```

   if there was a command-line option to force it to allow non-executables.
3. I then tried to solve the problem with `find`.  First I used regular expressions to expand the path list (I replace colons with spaces).  Then I invoke find, and it works correctly.  However, it searches all of the paths.  I cannot seem to find a way to tell it to stop the search early if it finds a good result.

   I did get this to work

   ```
    find ${MY_PATH_LIST//[:]/ } -name "$MY_TARGET_FILE" | head -n 1
   ```

   but it takes a long time to complete, because `find` is still doing an exhaustive search.

   *I need this to execute faster (exit on first result), because it would be run many times, with different parameters.*

**Does anyone have a better solution to suggest?**

Note that if all fails, I can write a non-bash solution.  Write now I'm hoping for a simple solution using existing tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use a script that simply tests (`-e`) for existence of a file and stops when the first one has been found:

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ $# -gt 0 ]] || { echo "Usage: $0 <filename> [pathspec]" >&2 ; exit 1 ; }
if [[ $# -gt 1 ]] ; then
        P="$2"
else
        P="$PATH"
fi

IFS=:
for DIR in $P ; do
        if [[ -e "$DIR/$1" ]] ; then
                echo "$DIR/$1"
                exit 0
        fi
done
```

Example:

```
$ ./search.sh 
Usage: ./search.sh <filename> [pathspec]

$ ./search.sh ls
/Users/danielbeck/bin/ls

$ ./search.sh pwd
/bin/pwd

$ ./search.sh ls /bin
/bin/ls

$ ./search.sh ls /usr/bin:/bin
/bin/ls
```

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. This works. I am surprised that there isn't a built-in command for this purpose. I'm going to wait a bit to see if there are any interesting comments. So far, it looks like this one will be going to you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use head to get the first result of the find command.

```
find `echo colon:separated:directories | sed 's/:/ /g'` -name filename | head -n1
```

Or in a function:

```
$ function findin { find `echo $1 | sed 's/:/ /g'` -name $2 | head -n1; }
$ findin this:that:other filename
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `which` command, and set the `PATH` variable just for the scope of that command. For example

```bsh
PATH="/path1:/path2" which "file1.txt"
```

will return `/path1/file1.txt` if it exists, otherwise `/path2/file1.txt` if it exists.

Comment: Actually no it only works for executable files, as you said.